Visual Studio 2022 Remote CMake CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE incorrect
I'm currently trying to work out how to use cmake, so I can start moving some of our windows c++ code into docker containers. As part of that work I need to start using a package manager and so I'm also working out how vcpkg works using the tutorial here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/vcpkg/get_started/get-started .
The tutorial uses cmake to build a simple c++ app that prints "hello world" out using the fmt lib. I have no problems getting everything to build in an ubuntu container or on Windows 11 (arm64).
However, if I open the local project as a CMake project (in VS 2022) and then remotely connect to the ubuntu container, building it fails.
1> [CMake] CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.28/Modules/CMakeDetermineSystem.cmake:176 (message):
1> [CMake]   Could not find toolchain file: /scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake

If I turn on cmake logging, I can see that VS is supplying the wrong location for vcpkg.cmake via the MAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE command line parameter.
../usr/bin/cmake -G "Ninja" -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE:STRING="/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake"

When it should be supplying - the root is missing
-DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE:STRING="/home/developer/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake"

If I do that manually on the remote host everything works, I guess I must be configuring vcpkg incorrectly. On the remote machine I followed the build instructions and defined VCPKG_ROOT and put the directory on the path and I can see them set in the environment ok.
I also have a CMakePresets.json file with this content:
{
  "version": 2,
  "configurePresets": [
    {
      "name": "default",
      "generator": "Ninja",
      "binaryDir": "${sourceDir}/build",
      "cacheVariables": {
        "CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE": "$env{VCPKG_ROOT}/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake"
      }
    }
  ]
} 

Where $env{VCPKG_ROOT}/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake points to the correct place.
I've also tried supplying it in the file CMakeList.txt, like so:
set(CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE
    ${VCPKG_ROOT}/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake CACHE STRING "Vcpkg toolchain file"
)

If I ssh into the remote host and try to do what vs is doing I can see VCPKG_ROOT is set as an envar, but if I put message("VCPKG_ROOT: ${VCPKG_ROOT}") in the cmakelist.txt it prints nothing.
# ssh to the remote host
cd /home/developer/.vs/helloworld
cat CMakeLists.txt
...
message("VCPKG_ROOT: ${VCPKG_ROOT}")
...

env 
...
VCPKG_FORCE_SYSTEM_BINARIES=1
PWD=/home/developer/.vs/helloworld
VCPKG_ROOT=/home/developer/vcpkg
...

cmake --preset=default
...
Preset CMake variables:
 CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE="/home/developer/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake"
-- CMAKE_HOST_SYSTEM_NAME: Linux
VCPKG_ROOT: * <-- NOTHING HERE *
-- Running vcpkg install
...

So I'm a bit stuck as to where VS is getting the wrong path from.
Any suggestions would be appreciated.

$env{VCPKG_ROOT}/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake points to the correct place. As for the log, this is not true. -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE:STRING="/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake" says $env{VCPKG_ROOT} is empty. You might need to restart the terminal or Visual Studio after setting VCPKG_ROOT env variable.

Its strange because I can see vcpkg_root "set" in the environment but cmake doesn't appear to see it, I have updated my question

CMake is case sensitive. The manual describes Use the syntax $ENV{VAR} to read environment variable VAR. You try to do it your own way for unknown reason.
